# DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind is not preserved datetime timezone

Tags: c#, json, json.net, date-formatting

I have below code:

```
                JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new    StringReader(content.ToString()));
                reader.DateTimeZoneHandling =            DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind;
                reader.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
                reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime;
                 myObj = JObject.Load(reader);
```

despite using DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind; still the date converted to local timezone. For example:

```
   "2015-02-02T12:01:14.548-0500"
```

changed to :

```
   "2015-02-02T11:01:14.548-0500",
```

Comment: any idea? or suggestion to use other methods...

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem, preferably including the initial JSON?  I just tried to reproduce this with a very simple test case, and can't.

Answer (score 0):

It is known issue of .net ([more about it](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1757))

A possible workaround is to use DateTimeOffset to parse date correctly and then convert it back to DateTime using method

```
static DateTime ConvertFromDateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset dateTime)
{
    if (dateTime.Offset.Equals(TimeSpan.Zero))
        return dateTime.UtcDateTime;
    else if (dateTime.Offset.Equals(TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(dateTime.DateTime)))
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime.DateTime, DateTimeKind.Local);
    else
      return dateTime.DateTime;   //Kind = Unspecified
}
```